# When did the Informed badge start?

Tags: discussion, badges

Scrolling through the list of badges today, I found one that I had never seen before: [Informed](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/258/informed). I've consulted the list several times before and have not seen it so it must be relatively new. This raises a few questions.

> 1. When did this badge become available?
> 2. Are new badges announced (on the main site or on meta)?

Comment: And suddenly there is a big spike in the number of Informed badges awarded.... (or so I assume)

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, and very few of the `Informed` users so far are new users, for whom the About page is intended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The new badge came into existence because of the [new about page](https://math.stackexchange.com/about). This innovation was [announced on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163254/were-rolling-out-a-new-quick-start-guide-to-help-new-users-learn-the-basics) but not on per-site metas.

One way to stay (more or less) current with the SE feature changes is to bookmark/favorite the Meta.SO thread [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange). At present it does not mention the new About page and Informed badge, but presumably will catch up soon.